# How to define the width of a HTML element dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a single container div with two child div's. The container div is 100% width. The child div's are left floated. The left div's width is not set because it's contents must decide it's width. The right div's width must be 100% minus the width of the left div.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="message-name"><p>User :</p></div>
    <div class="message-msg"><p>Some message</p></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="message-name"><p>User : </p></div>
    <div class="message-msg"><p>Some really long message that breaks to new line because it is too long to stay on this line. mmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmm</p></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
*{margin:0;pading:0;}

.container{
    width:100%;
    min-height: 20px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.message-name{
    height: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.message-msg{
    border: 1px solid red;
    min-height: 20px;
    float: left;
}
```

This is my attempt at using JQuery to dynamically set the width of the right div when it is added to the page dynamically:

```
$(document).ready( function(){

    var nameWidth = $(".message-name").last().width();

    alert(nameWidth);

    $(".message-msg").last().css("width","100%").width($(".message-msg").last() - nameWidth);

});
```

But it doesn't change anything.

How can I get the width of the left div and then subtract that from the width of the right div to ensure the right div does not break to a new line?

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zof15z6c/1/) of my attempt.

Comment: Your html is not well-formed. You are missing closing tags for several div's.

Comment: It's 2015. Use [flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

Comment: quite right, have corrected the htm

Comment: calc should be based on parent width and other element width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more efficient way to use flexbox is to just declare the `.message-msg` block to be flex: https://jsfiddle.net/84vocLbk/.  It'll be situated horizontally next to the `.message-name` and stretch the available width.

CSS:

```
.message-msg {
    border: 1px solid red;
    min-height: 20px;
    display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use flexbox, it's [support is wide enough](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) for most reasonable purposes.

No scripting required, much more FLEXible!

```css
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.container {
    width:100%;
    min-height: 20px;
    overflow: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.message-name {
    height: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid red;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
.message-msg {
    border: 1px solid red;
    min-height: 20px;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="message-name"><p>User :</p></div>
    <div class="message-msg"><p>Some message</p></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="message-name"><p>User : </p></div>
    <div class="message-msg"><p>Some really long message that breaks to new line because it is too long to stay on this line. mmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmmm mmmmmmmm</p></div>
</div>
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zof15z6c/6/)

Answer (score 1):

**Please try this**

```
$(".message-msg").last().width($(".message-msg").last().width() - nameWidth);
```

Border `2px` for each div is present. If you want to place it to the left then try this

`$(".message-msg").last().width($(".message-msg").last().width()-2 - nameWidth-2);`

[DEMO without removing border](https://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/zof15z6c/2/)

[DEMO after removing the border](https://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/zof15z6c/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
$(".message-msg").last().css("width","100%").width($(".message-msg").last().width() - nameWidth);
```

In thaat line you're setting the width to 100% then changing that width to **100% minus the variable nameWidth** You have to get width of last div to do calculations

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this with CSS.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zof15z6c/7/

This works by setting the overflow of the second div to `hidden` or `auto`. if your content is just a text I suggest setting it to `hidden` since the text would just wrap around.

### Changes to the css

```
.message-msg{
border: 1px solid red;
min-height: 20px;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

### Advantages:

1. Works on most browsers (tested in IE7)
2. The browser takes care of window resizes
3. Cleaner code

### Disadvantages

- Overflow should either be `hidden` or `auto`. This will not be an issue for you since you just have text.

Comment: `Edit in progress`. is not an answer